# Using querySelectorAll to target nested elements

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

How do I use `querySelectorAll` to select `<p>` with parent `<div class="entry-content">` only?

Eg.

```
<div>
    <p>ParagraphA</p>
    <p>ParagraphB</p>
</div>
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
    <p>Paragraph3</p>
</div>
    <p>Paragraph4</p>
    <p>Paragraph5</p>
```

I only want *Paragraph1 ~ Paragraph3* to be selected.

I'm currently using `var x = document.querySelectorAll("p");` which is selecting everything.

`var x = document.querySelectorAll("div > p");` is very closed to getting what I need, but I need to ensure only selecting all `<p>` elements within the `<div class="entry-content">` with class specified.

How can this be modified to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Specify the `div`'s class:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.entry-content > p');
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var entryContent = document.querySelector('.entry-content');//matches first
var p = entryContent.querySelectorAll("p"); //matches all
console.log(p);
```

```html
<div>
    <p>ParagraphA</p>
    <p>ParagraphB</p>
</div>
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
    <p>Paragraph3</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Paragraph4</p>
    <p>Paragraph5</p>
</div>
```